# Python For Loop Iteration Not In Expected Order

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, numpy

Please take a look at the first 2 lines of the following csv file. The first line is the field names, and the second line is the first line of the actual data.

I'm trying to iterate through the first line, and then store the values in their original order to an array.

```
age workclass   fnlwgt  education   education-num   marital-status  occupation     relationship     race    sex   capital-gain  capital-loss    hours-per-week  native-country  label
59  Private    307423    9th              5        Never-married    Other-service    Not-in-family  Black   Male    0              0                   50          United-States    0



reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    train_x = []
    train_y = []
    dic = {}

    for row in reader:

        row_x = []

        for title in row.keys():
            l = ['workclass','education','marital-status','occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'native-country']
            if title in l:
                value = get_dict[title][row[title]]
                row_x.append(value)
            elif title == 'label':
                train_y.append(float(row['label']))
            else:
                row_x.append(float(row[title]))


        train_x.append(row_x)
```

This is what I get for the first line:

[3, 5, 59.0, 0.0, 0, 50.0, 4, 35, 5.0, 0.0, 8, 307423.0, 4, 3]

As you can see, the ordering of the fields are wrong. (Note that the United States is 35, Private is 3...)

The csv lines are copied here for convenience as well:

```
age workclass   fnlwgt  education   education-num   marital-status  occupation     relationship     race    sex   capital-gain  capital-loss    hours-per-week  native-country  label
59  Private    307423    9th              5        Never-married    Other-service    Not-in-family  Black   Male    0              0                   50          United-States    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the csv using a DictReader, which will read the CSV into .. a dict.
The keys in a dictionary don't have a fixed order.
Have a look at the basic reader method

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader